# How to append name of folder to files inside with Shell script?

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm creating a Folder Action (Automator Mac) that processes new folders. My code does the first part. It trims the name of the dropped folder to 8 characters. Now it needs to append the trimmed folder name to all of the files inside and move the files up a level (where the folder was dropped). Finally, it needs to delete the empty folder.

```
--  /bin/zhs  pass inputs as parameters

for f in "$@"
    do
        autoload zmv // not sure where to put this
        if [[ $f == *""* ]] // currently set to be unfiltered
        then
            
        filename=$f:t;
        filepath=$f:h;
    
        dest=$(echo $filename | cut -c1-8); // var of dropped folder name. first 8 chars
        mv $filepath/{"$filename","$dest"} // trims dropped folder to 8 chars
        --zmv '(**/)(*).png' 't_$1$2.png' // this doesnt work here, BUT works in terminal. "t_" is temporary
    
        fi
    done
```

Why doesn't the zmv command seem work in the shell script? OR Is there a better way?

Comment: The shell used in automator or applescript is not the same as the one in your terminal. Try 'env' in the two environments and you'll see the difference. Automator uses bash for me (Sierra), so neither zmv nor autoload exist. Again, run just the command in automator and you'll see. Remember, the terminal is just an app that someone has told to use zsh.

Comment: Does this not work with bash's mv?